# How to get total values in mapping and details of each transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

I am trying to write a simple contract

```
contract students{
uint public totalTokens;
constructor() public {
    totalTokens = 800;
}
struct Students{
    uint amount; 
    string givenFor;
}

mapping (string => Students) studentsMappig;

string[] private studentsArray;

function setStudents(string _name, uint _amt, string _reason) public{
    Students storage student = studentsMappig[_name];
    totalTokens -= _amt;
    student.amount += _amt;
    student.givenFor = _reason;
    studentsArray.push(_name);
}
function getDetails(string addr) public view returns(uint amount) {
    Students storage student = studentsMappig[addr];
    return amount = student.amount;
}   
function getUsersCount() public view returns(uint) {
    return studentsArray.length;
}    
}
```

My issue are 2

1. I want to get how many total users which have tokens for which i tried getUsersCount() but it is giving every user mean not unique users
2. I want to get list of transactions done mean what was paid,to whom was paid and why was paid

thanks a lot for the help to understand me this and complete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an issue understanding what you wrote, what exactly is the meaning of the word "mean" for you?.

The function `getusersCount` gives the number of times the function `setStudents` was executed. You can add a mapping to know that a student has been registered

```
mapping(string => bool) isStudent public;
string[] private studentsArray;
mapping (string => Students) studentsMappig;
```

Also to be able to get a list of the transaction, you can add an event

```
transaction(string name, uint256 amount, string reason);
```

and modify the function `setStudents`

```
function setStudents(string name, uint _amt, string _reason) public{
    Students storage student = studentsMappig[name];
    totalTokens -= _amt;
    student.amount += _amt;
    student.givenFor = _reason;
    if(!isStudent[name]){
        studentsArray.push(string);
        isStudent[name] = true;
    }
    emit transaction(_address, _amt, _reason);
}
```

`studenstsArray.length` will now show the correct number of students

To get the detail of a student you must create a getter. To keep it simple you can do this:

```
function getStudents(string name) public view returns(uint256,string){
    require(!isStudent[name]);
    Students storage student = studentsMappig[name];
    return (student.amount, student.givenFor);
}
```

Then you can get this info using web3.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for reply but whole issue where you made the solution is address and i am not using address in this contract as its just saving and getting data if users independently for their eth addresses.  in my question changed _address with _name and can you tell me now how this mappings can be saved without using addresses

Comment: more over any student can be rewarded with token more than once so make a unique student check is not a good way here

Comment: Ok, I modified the code, now you are able to make several rewards to the same students and I changed the address by `name`. let me know if this solves your problem. If this solved it, please accept the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for so kindfull help. Need one small help, can we make an extra mapping also to store reasons? So we can call a function to show all the reasons (transactions) separately? I will accept answer!

Comment: it is not clear, the events will give you all the the information with all the reasons, names and amounts